# Angularjs getting controller to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's wrong with this controller/html setup?

**view1.html:**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="view1.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div >
        <p>The content is {{user.content}}</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**View1.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [ function GetAuthToken($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://dev.hypr.com/DevAPI/rest/login', {headers: {'API_KEY':'87d2e2c64d9a941f0520653e51eae4935f6a640256f2f85610d0b281fa26a9dd'}}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.Auth = data;
    });
},function GetUsers($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://dev.hypr.com/DevAPI/rest/uafapp/apps/testorigin/users/5',{headers: {'AUTH_TOKEN': GetAuthToken()}}).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.user = data;
  });
}]);
```

It keeps giving this error:

```
[Mon May 30 2016 13:11:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] "GET     /view1/view1.js" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Here's the path structure:
[Path structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9u64.png)

Comment: where do you include view1.js in your html? Also, I'm not sure if this would cause an issue, but I think you should move your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to the `<body>` tag, to make sure all your javascript files are loaded first (in `<head>`).

Comment: Also note that you are using a very old version of angular

Comment: @forgivenson not uncommon to put `ng-app` on `<html>` tag. Allows access to things like `<title>`

Comment: sorry, forgot the <script src="view1.js"></script>.  result is the same however.

Comment: Problem is clearly a path problem. We can't resolve that without knowing what your directory structure is relative to page

Comment: @charlietfl Good to know, thanks. I wasn't sure, as I've never tried that.

Comment: edited to include directory structure

Comment: You can actually use *ng-app* with <html> tag. This allows you manipulate the <title> tag.

However, the *ng-controller* should come after the *ng-app*, because what ng-app is doing is bootstrapping your angular app which you could handle yourself.

Comment: Something doesn't line up ...error is looking for `/view1/view1.js` but no directory like that so probably something to do with server routing

Comment: @charlietfl Oh yes that's true

Comment: @JamesFalter are you sure you are referring to the right _templateUrl_ link?

And I think you should inject the dependencies into the [ ] too like so 
**.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function GetAuthToken($scope, $http) { }]);**

Comment: yes, I am very sure

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest something which may not entirely solve your exact problem but it may actually help kick start your own angular development.

Now my experience comes from writing applications for one of the biggest blue chip companies and it relied heavily on interacting over a RESTful service.

I find it can be difficult to sometimes build up a structure with new frameworks and from all the research and testing i did i found the easiest way to kickstart development is to use 'HotTowel' which is linked [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel)

It will create the basic structure for your app, auto wire up controllers/views and comes with an example controller + view and routing.

Give it a go as it uses the best practices for writing angular applications.

Comment: What makes this different from https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme

Comment: There's a couple of things that make this different but i think the primary reason for using HotTowel on larger apps is the 'opinionated' approach to development. There is also a related stylesheet one can follow for best practices in laying out controllers, factories and services. In angular there is a million and one way of doing the same thing so going for a rigid approach can help, especially when it comes to maintaining an application or when working with other people on the same app.There is also an emphasis on separation of concerns and best practices for laying out the folder structure

Comment: one more thing @AkinjideBankole John Papa is well known in the Angular world and has some extremely helpful videos on PluralSight and for newcomers its a great place to start. It's worth noting he is the Google Developer Expert for Angular as well :)

Comment: However, Yeoman has been around for years now, and lots of Angular projects depends on it, I feel HotTowel is worth given a try, But Judging from the number of Github Stars, Fork and Contributors HotTowel can't stand Yeoman Angular

Comment: When it comes to project barebones and starter kits its really worth giving them a quick trial and see if it fits your workflow. One thing i would try to recommend to anyone and everyone working with Angular is to use the Angular Style Guide! Another reason i ended up using HotTowel was because i watched a couple of Angular videos on PluralSight as it was new to me and John Papa demonstrated very well how HotTowel worked and was constructed. Let me know what you think of it when you give it a go :)

Comment: I am currently using John Papa HotTowel, it's awesome but it can't be compared to Yeoman Angular generator